# In selenium, when i click on login button fields get cleared and login failed

Tags: selenium-rc

I am using selenium in my application.
In login page, I enters username and password. and click on Login button.
When i click on login button, fields gets cleared and remains on same page without any error or warning message.

All the xpath values are correct.
When used in record and playback it works.

Please provide solution.

Comment: Are you absolutely tied to Selenium RC, couldn't you use Selenium WebDriver? Selenium RC has been officially deprecated like two years ago. Anyway, after clicking the "Login" button, try opening up the JavaScript console. Is there any error logged? (also, if you tell us on which page it happens, or post a testcase so we could try it ourselves, that would be awesome)

Answer (score 0):

First see what is happening if u do it manual. If u provide login details to the page, is it redirect to next page or it remain the same page, I feel there is an issue in your test page.